# Loading Spring integration test context with instrumentation

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, instrumentation

In order to write an integration test with Spring I want to load the test application context with a custom class loader. The reason is that we use a LoadTimeWeaver (org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver or org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver). Unfortunatly the default Sun classLoader does not provide the required addTransformer method required by the LoadTimeWeaver. By using a javaagent with the sprint-instrument.jar on vm startup everything works fine.

But this is not a valid option for tests that shall be run from different machines, IDEs, etc.

I have tried a simple solution by extending the GenericXmlContextLoader and setting a SimpleInstrumentableClassLoader for my context loader:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/spring/_context.xml" }, loader = CustomApplicationContextLoader.class)
```

and

```
public class CustomApplicationContextLoader extends GenericXmlContextLoader {

    @Override
    protected void prepareContext(final GenericApplicationContext context) {
        super.prepareContext(context);
        context.setClassLoader(new SimpleInstrumentableClassLoader(ClassUtils.getDefaultClassLoader()));
    }
}
```

This resulted in errors like

```
Class [org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
```

probably because some classes are loaded by the default class loader and some classes are loaded by the instrumentation class loader.

Do you have a good solution?

Thank you for your help!
Chris

Comment: Do you have all the Spring jars on the classpath? Which ones do you have?

Comment: Although probably not all are relevant:
spring-context, spring-web, spring-jms, spring-test, spring-security-core, spring-security-web, spring-security-config, spring-data-jpa, spring-datacommons-cor, spring-tx, spring-webmvc, spring-instrument, spring-instrument-tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a custom class loader I wrote my own javaagent that can be loaded during runtime following this guide: http://dhruba.name/2010/02/07/creation-dynamic-loading-and-instrumentation-with-javaagents

I then extended SpringJUnit4ClassRunner to statically load the javaagent and it works.